# Why do extended classes have to re import in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Let's say I have a base class ParentClass that includes some import statements.

```
import flash.events.*;
```

If I then have a child ChildClass that extends my ParentClass and I want to do something with an event

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    public ChildClass():void{
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, childFunction);
    }
}
```

it doesn't work unless I add the import statement in the child class:

```
import flash.events.*;

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    public ChildClass():void{
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, childFunction);
    }
}
```

Why? If the child class is extending the functionality of the parent, why the need to re-import the classes that the parent required?

Answer (score 0):

One reason that import statements exist is that actionscript 3 classes can have the same name as other classes, provided that they exist in different packages.  Import statements tell the compiler which of these classes you are trying to use.

For example, if for whatever reason, you had previously made a class called **Event** in your this/is/an/example package, the compiler would need to see either an **import flash.events.Event** statement or an **import this.is.an.example.Event** statement to know which **Event** class you were using.  The same rule applies to child classes.